# Two columns match both elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'A':['x','y','z','r','x','z'],'B':[1,2,3,4,1,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

That gets me:

```
A | B
x | 1
y | 2
z | 3
r | 4
x | 1
z | 7
```

Then a list with **n** lists of two elements:

```
list_of_lists=[['x',1],['x',4],['z',3],['y',1]]
```

I want to find out if the **1st** element of every sub_list matches the column **A** and the second element matches the column **B**, getting something like:

```
A | B | Match
x | 1 | True
y | 2 | False
z | 3 | True
r | 4 | False
x | 1 | True
z | 7 | False
```

Thought creating two list for each element of the lists and do something like np.where with both conditions, but there must be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = list_of_lists, columns = df.columns)
# less readable but slightly faster
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['A','B'],zip(*list_of_lists))))
>>> df['Match'] = np.isin(df, df2).all(1)
>>> df
   A  B  Match
0  x  1   True
1  y  2  False
2  z  3   True
3  r  4  False
4  x  1   True
5  z  7  False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with helper `DataFrame` with left join and indicator=True parameter and then compare value `both`:

```
df1 = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=df.columns), how='left', indicator=True)

df['Match'] = df1['_merge'].eq('both')
print (df)
   A  B  Match
0  x  1   True
1  y  2  False
2  z  3   True
3  r  4  False
4  x  1   True
5  z  7  False
```

Comment: I was writing something exact to this, 
it's the right way to do it, I 'll change : `columns = df.columns`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `apply` method:

```
df['Match'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.tolist() in list_of_lists, axis=1)
df
   A  B   Match
0  x  1   True
1  y  2  False
2  z  3   True
3  r  4  False
4  x  1   True
5  z  7  False
```

To understand this, you can do an intermediate step and check result:

```
df['temp'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.tolist(), axis=1)
df

   A  B    temp
0  x  1  [x, 1]
1  y  2  [y, 2]
2  z  3  [z, 3]
3  r  4  [r, 4]
4  x  1  [x, 1]
5  z  7  [z, 7]
```

Then

```
df['Match'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['temp'] in list_of_lists, axis=1)
df
   A  B    temp  Match
0  x  1  [x, 1]   True
1  y  2  [y, 2]  False
2  z  3  [z, 3]   True
3  r  4  [r, 4]  False
4  x  1  [x, 1]   True
5  z  7  [z, 7]  False
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, went with a variation of this one at the end!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 df.apply(list, axis=1).apply(lambda x: True if x in list_of_lists else False) 

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

- Create a data frame of matches
- Merge with the original data
- Non-matches will be missing, so we need to fill in False for missing values

This approach, I believe, can scale up, even when the list of matches is large (so element-wise `apply` can be time-consuming, but left-join is manageable)

```
# data
data='''A|B
x|1
y|2
z|3
r|4
x|1
z|7'''
with open("a.txt", 'w') as f:
    print(data, file=f)
df1 = pd.read_csv("a.txt", sep="|")
list_of_lists=[['x',1],['x',4],['z',3],['y',1]]


# First, create a data frame of matches
matches = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['A', 'B'])
matches['Match'] = True

# left join with the original data, non-matches will be missing, so fill with False
df1.merge(matches, on=['A', 'B'], how='left').fillna(False)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  Match
0  x  1   True
1  y  2  False
2  z  3   True
3  r  4  False
4  x  1   True
5  z  7  False
```